# A word for "set to zero"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that entails the meaning of "I set it to zero"?

Note how this may not necessarily mean you *reset* something, as its default value may be something other than zero.

Comment: You *zeroed* it.  Perfectly legit techie talk.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is being set to zero? The answer may vary depending on if you're talking about a scale, the memory of a computer, or a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tare (from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tare#Verb)):

> To set a zero value on an instrument (usually a balance) that discounts the starting point

So for instance, if you have a kitchen scale you can say:

> I tared the scale. Throw in the next ingredient.

---

For measuring instruments other than weighing scales you can use:

Zero (from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zero#Verb)):

> To set a measuring instrument to zero; to calibrate instrument scale to valid zero.

Comment: How tare you!..

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are many ways to express this, and the most appropriate one depends on the context. For example

- *zero out*: phase out or reduce to zero. Or zeroed.
- *nullify*: make of no use or value; cancel out. Or nulled.

However, just using *set to zero* sounds reasonable to me...

Comment: +1 for *zero out*.  -1 for *nullify*.

Answer (score 0):

Tare

The correct scientific term is tare, as stated in the previous answer quoted from Wiktionary.

Comment: So what's the point of this "answer"?